# How safe openidconnect, when anybody can see signkey through the discovery points?

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am using Azure Ad openidconnect using .Net core MVC, i can see the signin key provided by azure ad through discovery endpoint. Now i am confused how safe openidconnect is when anybody can see the signin key used to sign my token.

Answer (score 1):

The key that is published is a so-called public key that belongs to a key pair that consists of that public key and the corresponding private key; the latter is supposed to be private to the owner, the former is not.

Comment: can you explain this bit more, still not cleared to me.

Comment: It is the essence of public private keypair (PKI) cryptography, please google that

Answer (score 0):

There are two cryptographically-linked keys involved (i.e. a key pair):

1. Private key: This is the key used to *sign* the token. In a typical scenario, only the token issuer (Azure AD, in this case) will ever have access to the private key.
2. Public key: This is the key used to *verify* a signature. In this scenario, the public key is used to test that the token signature was generated using the private key of this key pair.

If you know which issuer you trust (e.g. Azure AD), and you can open a secure communication channel to that issuer (e.g. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`), you can use that public key to verify that a given signed token really was signed by the trusted token issuer.